# Generating view with scaffolding for ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I'm doing a project with ASP.NET MVC3 and Linq to Entity . I have separated my data access layer through a different project and of course its not highly coupled with Model.

I have seen the scaffolding ( auto code generation for controller and corresponding views) feature which depends on Model.

Is there any tools or specific procedure through which I will be able to generate views for a specific controller like scaffolding do for ASP.NET MVC without involving model highly like MVC do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model that you are talking about here doesn't have to be a Database generated class. It can be anything, so what I would do is create a ViewModel (class) that will represent that view you want to display and use the Scaffolding functionality on that ViewModel.

You can then use something like an [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to bind your models to the view models

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the [MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) articles. Basically what you have to do is edit the default templates and power shell scripts.